# How is this bubble sort so fast?

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, bubble-sort

I came across a bubble sort algorithm that is ridiculously fast... Like sorts 100,000 full length ints in reversed sorted order in 0.03 seconds fast. I know that bubble sort is regarded as one of the most inefficient sorting algorithms, so what makes this one so much better?

I see that it stops sorting if no items are interchanged on the first pass (meaning it is already sorted), but that shouldn't affect the reversed order case.

p.s. Can anyone think of a way to sort this many ints faster? Maybe Radix sort?

```
void sort(int list[], int n)
{
    int i; 
    int j; 
    int gap;
    int swapped = 1;
    int temp;
    gap = n;

    while (gap > 1 || swapped == 1)
    {
        gap = gap * 10 / 13;
        if (gap == 9 || gap == 10)
        {
            gap = 11;
        }
        if (gap < 1)
        {
            gap = 1;
        }
        swapped = 0;
        for (i = 0, j = gap; j < n; i++, j++)
        {
            if (list[i] > list[j])
            {
                temp = list[i];
                list[i] = list[j];
                list[j] = temp;
                swapped = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this could be speeded up quite a bit by using three successive exclusive or operations rather than having a variable on the stack and using those three assignment statements.

Answer (score 3):

As commented it's a [comb sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comb_sort) .

For in place sorting, [quick sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) or [heap sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort) would be faster. If using a second temp array, then [merge sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) or [counting / radix sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort) are faster. Counting / radix sort should be the fastest of these.

Example code for counting / radix sort. It takes about .001 seconds on my system (Intel 2600K, 3.4ghz). This example code could be optimized a bit (like using a pointer for mIndex[j]), but I'm not sure if the compiler is already doing most of the optimizations you might make with minor code changes. It's possible that the processor overhead is so small that memory bandwidth is the limiting factor.

```
typedef unsigned int UI32;

UI32 * RadixSort(UI32 * pData, UI32 * pTemp, size_t count)
{
size_t mIndex[4][256] = {0};            // index matrix
UI32 * pDst, * pSrc, * pTmp;
size_t i,j,m,n;
UI32 u;

    for(i = 0; i < count; i++){         // generate histograms
        u = pData[i];
        for(j = 0; j < 4; j++){
            mIndex[j][(size_t)(u & 0xff)]++;
            u >>= 8;
        }       
    }
    for(j = 0; j < 4; j++){             // convert to indices
        n = 0;
        for(i = 0; i < 256; i++){
            m = mIndex[j][i];
            mIndex[j][i] = n;
            n += m;
        }       
    }

    pDst = pTemp;                       // radix sort
    pSrc = pData;
    for(j = 0; j < 4; j++){
        for(i = 0; i < count; i++){
            u = pSrc[i];
            m = (size_t)(u >> (j<<3)) & 0xff;
            pDst[mIndex[j][m]++] = u;
        }
        pTmp = pSrc;
        pSrc = pDst;
        pDst = pTmp;
    }

    return(pSrc);
}
```

Comment: How is it able to sort 100,000 elements in 0.03 seconds if it's still an O(n^2) algorithm? Can radix or counting really be that much faster than 0.03?

Comment: Would you mind letting me look at the implementation of radix that you used?

Answer (score 1):

Though it bears resemblance to a bubble sort, I think this is a [shell sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellsort), which is a much faster variant on the bubble sort.

Comment: ah ok, it was titled improved_bubble so I assumed it was some type of bubble sort

Comment: Worst case it's still an O(n^2) sort just like bubble sort, but it just a lot more difficult to arrange a worst case sort so in practice it works out faster.